# Python string to date time conversion issue in different versions

Tags: python, datetime

**python3.9.4 fails to convert string to datetime object**

Whats wrong with this specific date? same format is working with most dates of this type.

python 3.7

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 13 2019, 19:58:14) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Fri 07-02-2021  04:29:37:103', "%a %m-%d-%Y  %H:%M:%S:%f")
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 4, 29, 37, 103000)
>>>
```

python3.9.4

```
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 01:15:05)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("Fri 07-02-2021  07:21:08:382", '%a %m-%d-%Y  %H:%M:%S:%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Fri 07-02-2021  07:21:08:382' does not match format '%a %m-%d-%Y  %H:%M:%S:%f'
>>>
```

Comment: Which minor version of `python3.9` do you have. I tested this on `3.9.5` and I didn't encounter this `ValueError` problem. For the `python3.9` also could you add the code from the beginning just like in `python 3.7` snippet above.

Comment: edited : its python 3.9.4 and pasted complete code

Comment: Thanks! In the new post you removed the python3.7 part from the post. I think it is important to have that here.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening. I tested the same code in `3.9.4` and the string is still getting parsed to a valid date `datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 7, 21, 8, 382000)` without any problems.

Comment: Thanks ! I am parsing thousands of date with python3.9.4, program crashed one time and I got this input from backtrace, on checking with interpreter got ```ValueError```.

Comment: Also, not observing it now, program is running fine, still in interpreter it fails to do parsing

Comment: Perhaps that string contained some invisible characters which aren’t reproduced here?

Comment: I copied directly from backtrace and pasted in interpreter on my mac (3.7) and linux vm (3.9), It may be some special character, although it seems unlikely